# Как обновить Node JS в PHPStorm?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

Работаю на Ubuntu, в терминале пишу node -v - выдает 18.15.00, а пишу тоже самое в терминале PHPStorm, мне пишет 12.22.9, как обновить в PHPStorm ноду?

Answer (score 0):

Путь к файлам ноды можно указать в Settings/Language & Frameworks/Node.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете скачивать разные версии ноды в виде архива и указывать пути к разным версиям для каждого проекта